# LINQ to inner join with group by and some calculation

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I'm writing a LINQ to inner join with group by and some calculation. please guide me with correct code:

[image]

```
var flist =
            from a in _context.Customer
            join c in _context.InvoiceTransation on a.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID               
            group c by new { a.CustomerID, a.BusinessName } into g
            select new
            {
                g.Key.BusinessName,
                InvoiceAmount = g.Sum(n => n.InvoiceAmount),
                SaleReturn = g.Sum(n => n.SaleReturn_Amount),
                Receipt = g.Sum(a => a.Recipt_Amount),
                CurrentBalance = g.Sum(n => n.InvoiceAmount)
                                    - g.Sum(n => n.SaleReturn_Amount)
                                    - g.Sum(n => n.Recipt_Amount),
               
            };
```

Comment: You should develop and test the query in a database tool like Oracle SQL Developer or DBeaver. Then, use the working query in the C# environment

Comment: You asked the [exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74012088/join-in-linq-with-group-by) yesterday, only with a different title.

Comment: could not get answer

Comment: i think my question is not clear

Comment: Perhaps if you try to explain what calculations you need for each resulting column? That would be helpful for understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have already explain in images only thing I am not getting is opening balance

Comment: If u check image with dates u can understand what I needed

Comment: I am not getting any hint how to get opening balance

Comment: You should explain with text. Images should _enhance_ the understanding, not be _the only source_ for understanding the problem. Also, the image does not explain which parts you are having trouble with. And all explanations should be in the question post, not be added as comments to the question post.